# Android game loop not smooth

Tags: java, android, game-engine, interpolation

Trying to make very easy game loop, with one ball on screen (using interpolation).

Game loop:

```
    private double FPS = 50;
    private double TIME_STEP = 1000000000L/FPS;
    private double MAX_TIME = 1000000000L/5;

    Canvas canvas;

    double frameStart = System.nanoTime();
    double currentTime = 0;
    double accumulator = 0;
    float ratio = 0;

    while (running){

        currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        accumulator += currentTime - frameStart;

        frameStart = currentTime;

        if(accumulator > MAX_TIME){
            accumulator = MAX_TIME;
        }

        while (accumulator > TIME_STEP){
            screen.update();
            accumulator -= TIME_STEP;
        }

        ratio = Math.min(1f, (float)(accumulator / TIME_STEP));

        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        screen.render(ratio, canvas);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    }
```

Update method:

```
public void update(){
    pY = cY;
    cY -= 0.1f
}
```

Render method:

```
public void render(float ratio, Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawCircle(cX * ratio + pX * (1 - ratio),
            cY * ratio + pY * (1 - ratio),
            cR * ratio + pR * (1 - ratio), paint);
}
```

And that's all working not smoothing on my device, why? I'm changed FPS to 25 and to 60, but still not smoothing. Without interpolation game loop looks better but it's wrong way.